# goto specific cell upper left corner

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In excel there is a simple function to position active cell at left upper corner of window: Application.Goto Range("H40"), True

Is there anything like that for google sheets? If not can someone help me with the code? thanks.

Comment: Welcome. In my limited experience, it's rare to actually "move" the cursor. Perhaps you could explain what you want to do at cell H40?

Answer (score 0):

## Go To Cell

In your case you would deploy it as gotoCell('H40');

```
function gotoCell(A1NotationString) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(A1NotationString).activate();
}
```

- [Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String))